# how to JSON to Parse in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js

I have tree list components when I click on any item of the tree list it shows the result of JSON data. I don't wanna JSON format but parse format.

i have tried   `let json = JSON.parse(this.props.node, null, 4);` but it showing  **Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**

**You can visit the** [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-hugle-w9mmx?file=/src/DemoTree.js)

```
class NodeViewer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const style = styles.viewer;
    let json = JSON.stringify(this.props.node, null, 4);
    if (!json) {
      json = HELP_MSG;
    }
    return <div style={style.base}>{json}</div>;
  }
}

NodeViewer.propTypes = {
  node: PropTypes.object
};
```

Comment: Please show an example props.node -my bet is is is `undefined`

Comment: plz, check the link at the top.

Comment: its not clear what you are asking as the app seems to work showing the json data. 

you can't parse a node as its an object. if you want the raw string remove the indentation param

Answer (score 0):

Remove the indentation

```
let json = JSON.stringify(this.props.node);
```

Comment: yes. but how can I show the correct result when I click.